# How to update values for key using Object.entries in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to JS and React-native, I am creating an array of object for which key and title should be same which is Date and every transaction for every date(key) should be updated in it using Object.entries.

```
 if (isSuccess) {
      const content = data['content'];
      let m = new Map();
      for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        if (m.has(content[i]['createdAt'])) {
          let arr = m.get(content[i]['createdAt']);
          arr.push(content[i]);
          m.set(content[i]['createdAt'], arr);
        } else {
          let arr = new Array();
          arr.push(content[i]);
          m.set(content[i]['createdAt'], arr);
        }
      }
      let sortMap = new Map([...m.entries()].sort());
     
      const transaction = {
        title: 'Today',
        key: 'today',
        data: [],
      };

      Object.entries(transaction).map(([title, data]) =>
        console.log(`${title}: ${data}`),
      );
    }
```

**Format of Output**

```
{
title: 'Today'
key: 'today'
data: [{
icon: '',
transactionType: '',
amount: '',
time: '',
currency: '',
]
}
```

Comment: Not clear of what exactly you intend doing. What is the input and expected output.

Comment: update list of entries of object in key which is date 'createdAt' output I have mentioned in below